# How to get the sum of consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you were given a list which has the values of `[1,2,2,4,4,0]`. You need to create a function that takes a list of integers (positive / negative) and return the sum of the numbers that repeat consecutively. We need to return the result in a list format.

The answer for the aforementioned list would be [1,4,8,0].

I have tried creating a while loop in a for loop but that completely failed. I am totally stuck.

```
def sum_consecutives(lst):
    n_list = []
    total = 0
    count = 0

for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    print(sum_consecutives([0, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 0]))
```

This function should output `[0,21,5,4,18,0]`.

Comment: Your `for` loop contains no code; please show us what you've done so far and where exactly in the `for` loop you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group, then sum.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [sum(vs) for _, vs in groupby([1,2,2,4,4,0])]
[1, 4, 8, 0]
>>> [sum(vs) for _, vs in groupby([0, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 0])]
[0, 21, 5, 4, 18, 0]
```

`group` gathers up sequences of equal values, so `groupby([1,2,2,4,4,0])` returns something like `[(1,[1]), (2, [2,2]), (4, [4,4]), (0, [0])]`. (Rather than lists of equal items, it gives you iterators, but it's easier to visualize what it's doing with concrete lists.)

Comment: `[len(list(vs))*k for k, vs in groupby([0, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 0])]` would also work, or use `deque` to count without creating a hardcoded list.

Comment: Not really sure what you're going for in that comment. There's no need to count anything; `vs` is just a (sub)iterator of values in the original list.

Comment: since all values are equal, summing is equivalent to counting + multiplying. That's what I meant

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not sure any slight speed up you get will be worth the change in readability.

Comment: I'm not even sure that it will be faster, TBH

Comment: For long enough lists, it seemed to be. I did a quick check comparison of `sum(repeat(3, n))` to `3*len(list(repeat(3, n)))` for `n=10`, `n=100`, and `n=1000`; it looked like the cost of building a list became justified around n=100.

Comment: Trying to optimize python code based on compiled languages techniques can be frustrating, and counter-productive... small lists are probably built with a much bigger capacity.

Comment: Also, like anything else, whether you *need* to optimize depends very much on what kinds of lists the OP will be dealing with.

Comment: your solution is the simplest. Performance isn't that important. if you want speed, rewrite in a compiled language :)